# Azure dev ops boards: moving work items to different team boards

Tags: azure, devops

Hi I have created a new team within my azure dev ops project. I am trying to move items across from one teams backlog to the new team. For example one board is for local and one is for global so we have realised the card needs to be moved to this new global team board / backlog.

Is this possible and if so how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the Area path local to Global. All tasks/stories in local team would be reflected to global team. PFA  Screenshots below.
[local path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D02ti.jpg) [Global path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI0GJ.jpg)
[Global board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adcgT.jpg)